# C++ unordered_set of pointers allows modifying elements

Tags: c++, unordered-set

My apologies if this has been answered. I did search specifically for this issue, and could not find the answer.

unordered_set contains pointers to a user-defined type, one of whose memebers is a variable count.

Now, when I try to insert a new object -- specifically a pointer to the object, I check if it's already present. If it is, I just increment the count for that object.

**Question:** How does C++ allow me to modify the object, which is the key of my unordered_set?

```
auto iter =  mySet.find(w);
if(iter == mySet.end()) {
     mySet.insert(w);
} 
else { /* found the element. Increment the count. */
    (*iter) -> count += 1;
}
```

The above code works just fine and as expected. After the first time, any subsequent attempt to insert the object results in the count getting incremented.

The documentation says that any iterator for the unordered_set is constant "even if not preceded by const_". Could someone kindly explain what I am missing.

**Additional Info:** I do have the relevant hash and comparison functors defined, which are passed to the unordered_set as template args.

Best,

Comment: `*iter` is a const pointer value, not a pointer to a const object.

Comment: `unordered_set` enforces immutability on its elements - i.e., the pointers, not the pointees. It's still your responsibility to ensure that the changes you make to the pointee doesn't affect the output of the hash or comparison functors you are using.

Comment: Just as an aside, since you want a key and an associated value, you should probably be using a `map` instead of a `set`.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks. That is the point I wanted to ensure. Thanks for clarifying!.

Comment: @Jerry. You are right. The reason I am using a set here is that the object already contains the count. So, using a map in this case will be redundant. Thanks.

Comment: Elements in a set must not be modified.  If you're trying to count distinct elements, you should use a `map` where the key is the element and the value is the element count.

Comment: What is your comparison function?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an `unordered_set` of pointers, the key that's stored is the pointer itself, not your object's data. The collection will enforce the pointers to remain unchanged or a rehash will be needed.

By the way, if you're hashing the object's data but storing its pointer, eventually you might need to rehash manually if you change a field that's part of your hashing function.